# How to identify and kill longest running transaction?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

how can i list all running transactions ordered by the time they are running(descdendent)?
I want to kill a report that i've mistakenly started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unresearched/ untested but something like

```
SELECT at.transaction_id, 
       at.transaction_begin_time, 
       st.session_id
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st 
    ON at.transaction_id = st.transaction_id
ORDER BY transaction_begin_time
```

?

Comment: Yours and [Pinal's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916210/how-to-identify-and-kill-longest-running-transaction/7916316#7916316) give different result. Your query does currently list 22 transactions all with session_id=NULL whereas Pinals only shows the transaction of this query itself(Session_Id=57). Why?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Because my query lists **transactions** as specified in the question (including internal system ones) whereas Pinal's is currently executing statements which may or may not be participating in a transaction. If your reporting query is just doing a `select` looking at transactions isn't going to help.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: the word "authority" in Pinal's site should be taken as some form of humour, not actual "authority".

Comment: @gbn: I got to know his site as a hodgepodge of more or less useful scripts, good to know that i shouldn't trust them without thinking twice(deleted my answer that referenced [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/)).

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can find the ID of the continuing transactions by right clicking on the working database --> Reports --> All Transactions..
After determining the ID of the transaction, all you should do is creating a new query and running the following query "kill [transactionID]"
i.e: `kill 96`

Comment: Hmm, there is no currently open transaction within this database. Although my report is stopped meanwhile, i wonder why there are no other active transactions because at least a web-application is using heavily this DB. Thanks anyway.